# Atmel sam 4c wont run simple program, bricks memory after debugging

Tags: c, arm, embedded, atmel, atmelstudio

***Background and Setup***

Short of some Arduino development, I am new to the embedded world. Decided to jump in and learn! Got a Sam4C-ek with the ATSam4C32C microprocessor on it, also have the Atmel ICE debugger. Got everything hooked up and installed Atmel Studio 7. Went to the data sheets and found a user controllable LED on PC8, found the documentation on the PIO controllers and ended up with this code to just turn on that LED:

```
    #include "sam.h"
    #include "component\pio.h"


    int main(void)
    {
        /* Initialize the SAM system */
        SystemInit();
        PIOC->PIO_OER  = PIO_OER_P8;
        PIOC->PIO_PER = PIO_PER_P8;
        PIOC->PIO_SODR = PIO_SODR_P8;

      return 1;
    }
```

Defines from atmel libs:

```
#define PIOC       (0x4800C000U) /**< \brief (PIOC      ) Base Address */
#define PIO_OER_P8 (0x1u << 8) /**< \brief (PIO_OER) Output Enable */
#define PIO_PER_P8 (0x1u << 8) /**< \brief (PIO_PER) PIO Enable */
#define PIO_SODR_P8 (0x1u << 8) /**< \brief (PIO_SODR) Set Output Data */
```

***The Problem***

I hit start without debugging, it loads the micro, and nothing happens.... Hmm, okay so I did something wrong. Hit stop, hit "start with debugging and break" and I get the error message "Can't write to ARM memory". Well that's odd! Try a few things like a full chip erase via AS7 but ultimately have to jump the erase pin and reset the micro. Hit "start with debugging and break" it loads the program and breaks on "int main(void)" hit F10 to step through, SystemInit() goes great, hit the line  PIOC->PIO_OER  = PIO_OER_P8; and after "stepping over" it just goes into what looks like an infinite loop. If I hit stop and try to start again I get the same "Cant Write to Arm Memory" and have to jump erase.

Any ideas?!

Comment: I assume that your memory map and section placement are correct for the hardware you are using?

Comment: 'I am new to the embedded world' - oh, I'm so sorry, I hope you get well soon and return to real life :)

Comment: Yeah I doubled checked all that with the datasheet(s)

Comment: One thing to watch out for is whether you need to enable clocks/power for peripherals before you try to access them. If you deadlock the bus trying to access something which isn't turned on properly all kinds of weirdness can break loose.

Comment: the datasheet says the peripheral clock is not enabled on reset, but that you should be able to configure the ports.  but need it on before accessing an input.

Comment: how does your structure map to the address?  please disassemble the str instruction and the code that leads up to it insuring that the correct ldr is implemented with the correct address.  very easy for a compiler to not get it right when you point structures at ram (cross compile domains).

Comment: or even simpler try writing to an address in ram and reading it back, then using the debugger to verify, if you cant do that then talking to a peripheral wont work either and you have some build issue.  If that works and the peripheral doesnt, well first you need to turn this pio on anyway, then access it.

Comment: so first read the databook pio chapter, where it says about power/clocks/reset.  then search for PIOC in the datasheet from the beginning you find that peripheral id PID37 is the magic pid number for pioc, then you find the peripheral clock enable register that contains PID37 and it says you need to clear WPEN.  more research required.  welcome to bare metal programming.  99% is reading docs and interpreting them.  note that all docs are in some way flawed, some less than others but none perfect, hacking is required (or whatever word you prefer if you dont like that one)

Comment: olften there is a clock enable and a reset release.  not all chips do it that way though, not all pios are treated equal, some are powered up on reset some are not depends on the vendor.  again 99% of the work is reading docs and diagrams and schematics (and reading between the lines to find the truth).

Comment: Yeah sorry I haven't replied. I actually started doing everything listed above, still hardfaulting. Decided to try PIOA out of desperation, guess what works like a charm. PIOA....